# Disable sonar rule - Lines should not be too long for C# project using DotSettings

Tags: c#, sonarqube, resharper, sonar-runner

We want to disable sonar inspection Lines should not be too long for our c# project. We already created DotSettings file where we customize some of the inspection rules. However we were not able to find option to disable rule lines not be too long using dotsettings. Can somebody let us know the workaround for the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SonarQube .NET integration pieces use Roslyn in the back. So every standard Roslyn tooling works with SonarLint or SonarC#. The rule activation can be controlled through .ruleset files, and not dotsettings. Note however, if you want to disable a given rule for all .NET projects, them you should do this change on your C# quality profile in SonarQube.

Comment: I am able to change some of the c# quality profile rule  via DotSettings how i don't get option to change rule lines should not be too long for C#. Also how can i change C# quality profile in SonarQube?

Comment: I am able to get rul set file. How can i specify rule set file into teamcity?